# How to add scripts and styles for EXACT page in Wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I am well aware of the WP hooks `admin_print_scripts-$mypage`, `admin_print_styles-$mypage` but they seem to trigger only for pages registered with `$mypage = add_management_page( ... )`, `add_options_page()`, etc. It's quite clear you won't be able to use these for sub-generated pages with totally different markup unless you keep the URL intact (pass data using POST).
As it's my first encounter, i came up with solution which is quite simple - conditions for `$_GET['page']`,`$_GET['action']`(for ex.) and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` then hook `admin_print_scripts/styles` with `wp_enqueue_script/style ()` . It works just well but is it the way to go?

Comment: Please refer below link http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/07/01/how-to-design-and-style-your-wordpress-plugin-admin-panel/

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused as to why you have any pages which are not registered using the WordPress functions. If the plugin/theme is complicated enough to need several distinct pages (not just one page with some tabs) then I suggest you add a standalone page using: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page and then have several sub pages using: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page